# Using variable in another stage in declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a declarative `Jenkinsfile` which looks like this. In the stage "build" I define the variable `customImage` which I would like to use in the stage "Push".

Unfortunately I cannot get this to work.

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def commitHash = GIT_COMMIT.take(7)
                    echo "Building Docker image for commit hash: " + commitHash
                    def customImage = docker.build("myimage:${commitHash}")
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Push") {
            steps {
                echo "Pushing Docker image to registry..."
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry(REGISTRY_SERVER, REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS) {
                        $customImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This works already as presented except for the syntax issue `$` in `$customImage.push()`. You need to remove that `$`.

Comment: I tried but this doesn't seem to work. Jenkins complains with: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: customImage for class: WorkflowScript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to define the variable at a scope, where you can access it later, i.e.

```java
def customImage
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def commitHash = GIT_COMMIT.take(7)
                    echo "Building Docker image for commit hash: " + commitHash
                    customImage = docker.build("myimage:${commitHash}")
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Push") {
            steps {
                echo "Pushing Docker image to registry..."
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry(REGISTRY_SERVER, REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS) {
                        customImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```